# How to show 'pending' and 'success' when sending a job?

Tags: laravel

I have the following store function

```
public function store(MessageRequest $request, $chatId) {
    MessageJob::dispatch($chatId, auth()->user(), $request->message);
    return response()->json(null, 200);
}
```

and this is my job

```
public function handle(): void {

        $message = Message::create([
            'chat_id' => $this->chatId,
            'user_id' => $this->userId,
            'message' => $this->message,
        ]);


        broadcast(new MessageSent($message));
    }
```

now whenever a message is send I immedaitely get `response 200` and I show the message on the chat using

**Before Job done** I add message to 'waitings' list and after I get success I remove it from the waiting

```
const id = Math.random() * 10
waitings[id] = message
await axios.post(`/messages/1`, {message: message})
delete waitings[id]
```

**After Job done** it gets added to the messages

```
Echo.channel(`messages-1`)
    .listen('MessageSent', (message) => {
        messages.value.push({
            id: message['id'],
            content: message['content']
            created: message['created'],
        })

    });
```

what I want is to have `delete waitings[id]` done after the `Job` is  done instead of immediately  after request success

Answer (score 0):

If I am not confused, you should put the `delete waitings[id]` inside the `.listen`.

The new code should be:

```js
const id = Math.random() * 10
waitings[id] = message
await axios.post(`/messages/1`, {message: message})

Echo.channel(`messages-1`)
    .listen('MessageSent', (message) => {
        messages.value.push({
            id: message['id'],
            content: message['content']
            created: message['created'],
        })

        delete waitings[message['id']] // Now that it was sent, you can delete it
    });
```

Comment: the message['id'] is the database `id` while the waitings `id` is random number for the placeholder.  I think my method is completely wrong to track, I mostly want a way so that when a user  sends a message he sees it in chat with "loading" and when job down for me to show "success" as in sent

Comment: you are right, totally my bad. I think you should get a message id as a response and then use that one, the issue is how the code is writting, that is currently no possible because you reate the message inside the Job

Comment: are messages usually created on the main thread and not queued? I am a bit in confusion about which should be queued and which not